# How can I check the first process that is run? I can see both init and linuxrc in root folder

Tags: linux, boot, busybox

I get a modified Linux installation on QNAP x86 based NAS. 
In the initrd image file, I noticed there are both a init script `/init`and a symbolic link that points to a different program(busybox): `linuxrc ->/bin/busybox`.

How can I figure out which one is the init process that is run every time the system is booted?

Comment: symbolic link points to the actual script, which gets to be run. I can not really understand your question what you are trying to figure out here. Symbolic links do not run. They are just pointers to the files which in turn do  something when someone invokes the symlink.

Comment: The init is a script. Linuxrc links to busybox binary. The two are different.

Answer (score 0):

`/linuxrc` is launched on an old-style [initrd](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/initrd.txt), `/sbin/init` is launched on a newer-style initrd, `/init` is launched on an [initramfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt). Initrd and initramfs are two mechanisms with the same purpose: to mount a filesystem in RAM from which storage drivers can be loaded. Initrd is older, initramfs is the current recommended method.

Some distributions have kept a setup from the days before initramfs existed, and call the image initrd even when it's an initramfs image. So the fact that you have a file called `initrd` does not mean that it's loaded as one. Some distributions, evidently including yours, have kept a file structure on the initrd/initramfs that allows the same directory tree to be used on either. The format of the image file is different, however.

To figure out whether you have an initrd or initramfs, the easiest way is to run

```
file /path/to/initrd
```

If you have a cpio archive, it's an initramfs. If you have an initrd, it's <rummage> “Linux Compressed ROM File System data”.